# Two cycles of moadim

Tags: commentaries, chagim-holidays, nissan, tishrei

The major moadim (as mentioned in Vayikra 23) seem to be divided into two main cycles; the Tishri cycle in the fall and the Nisan cycle in the spring. The first festival in Tishri is Rosh HaShanah, the first one in Nisan is Pesach. Also both of these start a 'new year' in their own way as Tishri Marks the head of a year, and Nisan Marks the head of the months (many commentators explain the reason for this).

But on a more spiritual level what does one learns from both of these half-year cycles comparing them to eachother?. What do these cycles try to tell us?

P.s. And what can one learn if one would take these cycles as whole-year cycles:
So if we take the whole year from Tishri to Tishri v.s. all the months from Nisan to Nisan as two ways of looking at a religious/spiritual year - full of moadim - in stead of half year cycles, and take the order of Vayikra 23 as a basis for the full year cycle starting with Nisan, and would take this same order but instead - in the case of a Tishri cycle - would start off with Rosh HaShanah (instead of Pesach) and after it follow all the other moadim described after their order in time, and would compare such cycles.. what would they tell/teach us?

Comment: Where do you see a cycle starting at Rash Hashana? (Besides for flipping the year.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann Mishnah Rosh Hashanah 1:1 specifically defines Rosh Hashanah’s “new year” status. “The first of Tishrei is the beginning of the year [rosh hashanah] for years..."

Comment: Where do you see that there are two cycles for Yamim Tovim?

Comment: @DonielF I didn't there are two half year cycles, which are composed of one whole-year cycle. You can only make two halves out of one cycle. My point was if one would take each of the beginnings of those half-year cycles as a start for the moadim than what would they tell/teach us. It's a rethorical question.

Comment: But where do you see that it’s two half-year cycles which comprise one whole-year cycle, as opposed to one cycle, period? If you’re just coming up with that and asking for a deeper meaning, that makes for a very poor question.

Comment: @DonielF https://ohr.edu/seasons/5759/tishrei.pdf

Comment: @DonielF http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/2842/jewish/Our-Other-Head.htm

Comment: @Levi That’s not at all what you’re discussing. You said two half-year cycles. Both of those articles make reference to a yearly cycle of months beginning in Nissan and a different yearly cycle of years beginning in Tishrei (compare Mishnah Rosh Hashanah 1:1).

Comment: @DonielF I understand, that's a mistake on my behalf I didn't phrase myself correctly. I just used the term half-year because Nisan and Tishri are seperated by at least a half-year, in another sense they both form two halves as one is composed of spring festivals and the other of fall festivals. But what you said is correct and that was what I ment...

Comment: @DonielF Hopefully you will understand my question in the right light now; "if one would start at Nisan/Tishri and it's  first festival from that point to last festival from that point (I.e. the next Nisan/Tishri)  then what would the order in which the festivals would occur teach or tell us?" Is this something I can ask this way, or should I remove my question?

Comment: @Levi I think that’s still irrelevant. Once you’re pointing to Tishrei and Nissan as being Roshei Shanah for two separate things, you might also notice there are as many as seven different Roshei Shanah (remainder of Mishnah on 2a and Braisa on 6b), as well as the fact that Pesach is listed in that Mishnah (as explained on 4a) as being the Rosh HaShanah for Regalim. That should be enough to clear up the confusion. (Con’t)

Comment: In general I don’t advocate deleting questions, unless they’re not real questions (read: misposted or rants in disguise), but remember that being closed isn’t a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if these are the two cycles to which you refer, but Rav Aharon Feldman shared a beautiful thought about the two cycles 
1) Pesach, Shavuos, and Sukkos. 
2) Rosh Hashona, Yom Kippur, Sukkos.
 Pesach is when the Jewish people were appointed by G-d as messenger. Shavuos is when we fulfilled our *shlichus* by receiving the Torah. And Sukkos is when we returned and said "We have fulfilled our mission." Unfortunately we sinned (with the Golden Calf) and nearly did not fulfill our mission. Therefore we needed Yom Kippur before we could have celebrate sukkos.